# Why we can't assemble LES AX,SP instruction in assembly 16?

Tags: assembly

The instruction `LES AX`,`SP` has the machine code `C4C4` it can't be written in the assembler but if the disassembler find `C4C4` , it will convert it to `LES AX,SP`

I'm using the dos `debug` as an assembler.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disassemblers just don't make a lot of effort to suppress illegal instructions. They were written to disassemble real code and mechanically translate the modRM byte.  Particularly the case for debug.com, it being *small* was a lot more important than it being accurate 30 years ago.

It is illegal because LES requires a far pointer, can't get one from SP.

Comment: The strange thing is that I've found it while tracing interrupt 10 in BIOS where ah=0 , and strictly after it ,
the interrupt Ends and done !!

Comment: That's what happens when you disassemble data instead of code.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer my self now , The Problem as I mention in the comment above , is that I was tracing BIOS interrupt in Protected mode , And This is wrong , because protected mode din't give any access to BIOS interrupts  , and so the tracing is wrong and it's normal to face illegal instructions in an illegal trace .